# Clear a sheet in Excel 2013 with office add-ins

Tags: javascript, excel-2013, office-addins, office-js

I have an office add-in that generates a report (tables). The second time the user is running it I want to clear that sheet.

I have been trying around and have read through the documentation but I cant find a way to do this.

Have anyone found a solution to solve something like this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `sheet.getRange().clear()` method.

Example:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    sheet.getRange().clear();
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

That solution works fine for me also in Office365 and Office 2016. But not for 2013 since there is no Excel object for me then (or atleast we havent got that to work).

Comment: Correct, this is for Office 2016+ only.  You can check whether you're in a supported host by doing `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", 1.1)'

Comment: My apologies, I somehow thought you were asking for both 2013 and 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but you can use the below function to clear your generates report tables on Excel 2013.

```js
    DeleteTableDataOnExcel2013(tableID, callback) {
        Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync(tableID, Office.GoToType.Binding, function (asyncResult) {
            Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(tableID, function (getByIdAsyncResult) {
                if (getByIdAsyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    const binding = getByIdAsyncResult.value;
                    binding.clearFormatsAsync();
                    binding.setFormatsAsync({ cellFormat: { cells: { row: Office.Table.Headers }, format: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', fontColor: '#000000', fontFamily: 'Verdana', fontSize: 12, wrapping: true, fontStyle: 'normal', width: 8.43, height: 15 } } }, function (formatResult) {
                        binding.deleteAllDataValuesAsync();
                        Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync(tableID, function (releaseAsyncResult) {
                            callback();
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```